# How to validate base 64 string with Laravel 4.2

Tags: image, validation, laravel, base64

Trying to find best way to validate image in base 64 with Laravel.

I'm getting string from input like below:

```
'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxAQDw8PDxAQEA8NEA0PDxAQDw8NEBAQFBEWFhQSFBQYHCggGBolGxQVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNyguLi8BCgoKDg0OFBAQFywcFxwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsNywsNywrLCssLCw3Kys3LCssKywsKysrKywrKyssK//AABEIAMABAAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAACAwABBAUGB//EADgQAAIBAwIEAwYEBQUBAQAAAAECAAMREgQhBRMxQVFhgQYiMnGRsRQjocFCUtHh8AczQ2LxJBX/xAAZAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAX/xAAfEQEBAQEAAwEAAwEAAAAAAAAAARECAxIhMRNBUXH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/APamLdoxpnqGequ0C7xecBmgZTFrR2UrKKykvIHXlWgCM'... (length=5935)
```

But I can get any simple random string (Ex. 'LoremIpsum').
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to validate? What are the rules the image needs to meet?

Comment: I want to validate base64 format, which I use on the front end part.

Comment: Just if it is a correct base64 string? Or if it is a valid image? Or if the image format matches declared mime type?

Comment: Yes, validate for valid base64 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
 if (!base64_decode($value))
```

base64_decode will return false on non base64 string.